# How to change the color / transparency of panel through script in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to change the color/transparency of my some panels on some conditions.
Like we can change the text color by `.GetComponent<Text>().color =`
How can we do the same for panels?

Comment: A "panel" always has an `Image` component ... and then just the same way I'd say ....

Comment: Any question can and will receive downvotes if it doesn't meet the [Quality Standards of StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which include a complete enough reproducible example, code snippets, your exact setup and own research .. this question is lagging all of these

Answer (score 0):

the panel contains image component which you will use to change the transparency 
you can change the color and transparency of image like this:

```
    public Image image;
    void Start () 
    {
          image = GetComponent<Image>();
          var tempColor = image.color;
          tempColor.a = 1f;
          image.color = tempColor;
    }
```

`image.a` is the attribute for transparency, you can assign a value between 0 and 1 to it.

Comment: NullException occuring on 'var tempColor = image.color;'

Comment: this is weird , can you send me the exception message ?

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEditor.Graphs.Edge.WakeUp () (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Graphs/UnityEditor.Graphs/Edge.cs:114)
UnityEditor.Graphs.Graph.DoWakeUpEdges (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] inEdges, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] ok, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] error, System.Boolean inEdgesUsedToBeValid) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Graphs/UnityEditor.Graphs/Graph.cs:387)

Comment: modified code:

              `  ldpanelimage1 = GetComponent<Image>();`
              `  var tempColor = ldpanelimage1.color;`
                `tempColor.a = 1f;`
               ` ldpanelimage1.color = tempColor;`

Comment: and make sure you are use Image from this namespace ?
using UnityEngine.UI;

Comment: Try exiting and restarting Unity.

This is an error in Unity's code, which is located in UnityEditor.Graphs.DLL. 

If the error persists, you can upgrade Unity or report it as a bug.